# swt: how to handle copy/paste operation?

Tags: swt

I'm using SWT Text component. Do someone know how can I handle copy/paste operation and modify data when copying to the buffer and when copying from the buffer? I don't want just handle Ctrl-C Ctrl-V because there are a lot of other keys to do that thing (Shift-Del/Shift-Insert) and even user can override these keys.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your own text component based on Text or StyledText and override copy() and paste(). This can do what you want.

Don't forget to override checkSubclass method.

Comment: Overriding these methods does not seem to do anything for me.  I have heard that it might be platform-specific?

Comment: It's platform-specific - yes - but you can use super.copy() super.paste() if you want to use default behavior in certain case.

Answer (score -1):

The package you should look at is: import org.eclipse.swt.dnd.*

Simple example:

```
Clipboard clipboard = new Clipboard(parent.getDisplay());
            String data = sb.toString();
            clipboard.setContents(new Object[] { data }, new Transfer[] {    TextTransfer.getInstance() });
            clipboard.dispose();
```

Comment: I think the original question is about how to override the copy/paste behaviour, and not about what to do in handling code.